# Can I blank out a field in TFS using a work item template?

Tags: tfs, tfs-workitem

I have a number of TFS work items where I need to blank out a particular field (the Assigned To picklist). I would like to do this using a template, but if I leave the field empty in the template, it interprets that as meaning I don't want to change that field. Is there any way I can define a template where I tell it that I want to empty this field, when I apply the template to my work items? Maybe some special placeholder like , something like that?

Note: I'm working on TFS work items through Visual Studio 2010; and for some reason the web interface isn't accessible in this project.

---

Update; for anybody not familiar with work item templates, they are a way to define a batch of changes to make to a work item, which can be applied to one or more items in a single action. This functionality is part of [Team Foundation Server Power Tools](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=248625). Here's an example of a template I use frequently:

[image: TFS work item template example]

Once you have a suitable template defined, you can select a number of work items from a view in TFS, right-click, and apply the template to all of them with just three mouse-clicks in total:

[image: Applying a template to several work items]

Comment: What do you mean by "template"?

Comment: Templates are a feature installed with Team Foundation Server Power Tools, which let you define a set of values which you can apply all in one go to a TFS item. For example I use them to update the status and the owner and the history comment all in one go when I start or finish working on a bug retest.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you mean by template.  But if you have a bunch of work items and you want to do a bulk-update to set Assigned To to blank, I would do that in Excel.

Run a Work Item Query in Visual Studio, click the Open in Office/Excel button, copy-paste blank into the Assigned To field across all the rows, then hit Publish in the Team ribbon tab to publish those changes back to TFS.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I'd prefer to use a template because it's faster. You can select a few work items and apply the template with just three mouse-clicks - much quicker than opening up the query in Excel and saving changes back.